# More efficient use of apache?

Tags: linux, apache

I have a django app running on ec2. It is a micro instance, and I see 62% of my memory is being consumed by an application that has zero users. This seemed quite high to me, so I did:

```
$ ps aux|grep apache
root      9318  0.0  1.4 204924  9052 ?        Ss   23:01   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
ubuntu    9323  0.1  4.7 234824 28588 ?        S    23:01   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
ubuntu    9324  0.1  4.7 235176 28780 ?        S    23:01   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
ubuntu    9325  0.1  4.8 235536 29088 ?        S    23:01   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
ubuntu    9326  0.1  4.7 234808 28564 ?        S    23:01   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
ubuntu    9327  0.1  4.7 234952 28620 ?        S    23:01   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
ubuntu    9328  0.1  4.7 235136 28892 ?        S    23:01   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
ubuntu    9329  0.1  4.6 234856 28140 ?        S    23:01   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
ubuntu    9330  0.1  4.8 235480 29356 ?        S    23:01   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

Why are there so many processes here? What are all these processes doing? Is there a way to make this more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may depend on the Apache worker you are using, but it is likely that Apache will use a separate process for each incoming connection.  In order to serve incoming connections rapidly, it keeps a pool of connection handlers open, which is why there are so many processes.

The level of memory usage will be because, regardless of the number of users, Apache has to keep all/most of your application, Django, Python and any third-party apps you are using in memory to be able to serve the site efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

For your case this is caused becase of your configuration. Try plain with the StartServers, MinSpareServers and MaxSpareServers, on your configuration to tune this. for more information and options on tuning see [here](http://linuxstuffs.wordpress.com/apache-optimization/)

Furthermore is you run the 'free' command you will propably see that most of the 62% memory is cached as a buffer, for the apache to be ready to serve faster. **In case you need it, it will allocated to your ever applications, and buffer will be just deleted**.